# Jmeter Multiple data for update query

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am working on an update query using JMeter JDBC configuration. I have parameterized the input parameter and for now, it updates only one record as per the parameter value in each iteration. However, I want to update in bulk records to avoid long duration. Let's say I want to update 3k records at once. So how can I achieve this using JMeter parameterization for update query?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to do it on SQL query level.

However if you need this to be done using JMeter:

1. Connect [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and provide your 3000 parameters there
2. Configure JDBC Request sampler to read the data from the CSV file
3. Increase number of threads on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level to 3000

   [image]
4. Add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) to your thread group and set `Number of Simulated Users to Group by` to "3000"

   [image]

This way JMeter will run the JDBC Request sampler with 3000 threads at exactly the same moment in time, hopefully this is what you're looking for

Comment: @Dimitri, Is there a way to allocate block size for parameter in jmeter. This will solve my problem. Otherwise i need to write some logic.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "allocating block size", if you need to assign specific set of data to each virtual user the easiest way is going for a CSV file per user and reading them via [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions. Alternatives are ["Sharing Mode" of the CSV Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy/) and  [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/)